# How does one create and use a media player within a fragment in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, android-fragmentactivity

so i'm making this application that uses alot of media players and everything has worked fine until I added swipey tabs and started using them - this is how i was creating media players before the tabs

MediaPlayer b1loco = MediaPlayer.create(Fragment_4.this, R.raw.loco);

b1loco.start();

But now it gives me this error,

The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment_4, int)

ideas anyone??

heres a screenshot -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnyIn.png

Comment: GetActivity() instead of Fragment_4

Comment: Thanks worked (GetActivity() instead of Fragment_4.this) - confused me for a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fragment does not have a context and can not be used as a context. A fragment is inside an activity and the activity controls the fragment. If you need a context you should request it from the activity by calling `getActivity()`.